# Check if a field exists in a context.table in python-behave

Tags: python, gherkin, python-behave

I'm having trouble trying to check whether a field exists or not in a table:

```
| category    | info                       |
| Electrician | 74300 Paris 04 50 65 43 21 |
```

---

Let's say my table usually contains a "name" field, but in this specific case it doesn't. How do I check the existence of the "name" field in this case?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply check if your column is present in the `headings` attribute of the table. This attribute is also present when dealing with a single row instance, just so you know.

```
if 'name' in context.table.headings:

    do_something()
```

However, I personally prefer handling tables as dictionaries, using something like this

```
def make_dict_from_row(row):
    """
    creates a dictionary of arguments (**kwargs) from a behave
    table row.
    """

    cells = [cell if cell != '' else None for cell in row.cells]
    return dict(zip(row.headings, cells))
```

Using this you could simply do this

```
if 'name' in row:

    do_something()
```

See the [table model](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/api.html#behave.model.Table) for further reference.

Comment: `Row` class already has `.as_dict()` method. I'm using behave 1.2.5.

Comment: @K.H. interesting, I can't remember which version I was using when I posted this answer  and if this was available on my version, but this removes the need for the custom `make_dict_from_row` method.